# complex limit : $\lim_{z\rightarrow -3}\frac{\log(z+3)}{e^{\cos(z)}}(z+3)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z$ be a complex number. Does the following limit exists ?
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow -3}\frac{\log(z+3)}{e^{\cos(z)}}(z+3)$$
where $\log(z)$ is the complex logarithm.

Comment: And what *is* “the complex logarithm”? You make it sound as if it was a function.

Comment: $\log(z)=\ln(\mid z\mid) + i \phi$ where $\phi$ is the argument of $z$.

Comment: And what is **the** argument of $z$?

Comment: the argument of $z$ is the angle that makes $z$ with the real line. $z=\mid z \mid (\cos(\phi)+ i\sin(\phi))$.

Comment: And if $\phi$ is the angle of $z$, is $\phi+2\pi$ also the angle of $z$? After all,$$\cos(\phi+2\pi)+\sin(\phi+2\pi)i=\cos(\phi)+\sin(\phi)i.$$

Comment: so $\log$ is not a function ?

Comment: If you make a choice of $\phi$ for each $z$, then it becomes a function. If, say, for each $z\in\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$, you pick the only argument from $(-\pi,\pi)$, then you get the so-called main determination of the logarihtm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why $e^{cos(z)}$ term?  When $z=-3$ term is not $0$.  The main question is $\lim_{z\to 0} zln(z)=0$.

Comment: yes indeed. so how do we prove the last limit ?

Comment: @Dicordi L'Hopital's rule is the simplest way  $zln(z)=\frac{ln(z)}{1/z}$.  Take derivatives of numerator and denominator and get $\frac{1/z}{-1/z^2}=-z\to 0$.